# Joining condition showing inappropriate result

Tags: database, oracle, join, left-join, where-clause

```
    SELECT   a.name,
             nvl(c.bill_amount,0),
             b.status
        FROM  table_1 a left outer join table_2 b
        ON  a.name = b.name and
           b.status = 'YES'
        left outer join table_3 c on B.phone_number = C.phone_number
             AND B.email = C.email
             where 
             a.VALID = 'Y';
```

I wrote this query recently, the condition b.status = 'yes' is not fulfilled in the above query and status shows NULL value in it. I want to refine my records according to this condition b.status ='yes'.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
   SELECT  a.name, nvl(c.bill_amount,0), b.status
   FROM  table_1 a left outer join table_2 b
   ON  a.name = b.name
   left outer join table_3 c on b.phone_number = c.phone_number
   where 
   a.VALID = 'Y' and
   b.status = 'YES' and
   b.email = c.email
```

Comment: @Akshay - See my updated answer please. This works fine